# Installing Wine and getting an error

Tags: 16.04, apt, wine

I'm running a rented vps that was/is an Ubuntu 16.04 headless server that I installed Xfce Workstation on top of. I connect via remote desktop. I've not had any problems up until this point.

I am attemping to install Wine on my Ubuntu workstation. I am following the instructions given here:

https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu

I am at the point where I ran this line:

```
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
```

This didn't give me any errors although the next line did:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I am getting this:

> root@xxxxx:/home/xxxxxx# apt-get update Hit:1
>   ttp://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease Hit:2
>   ttp://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
>   Hit:3 ttp://mirrors.linode.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
>   Ign:4 ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
>   Get:5 ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [1,189 B]
>   Get:6 ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]
>   Get:7 ttp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [107
>   kB]                                                           Hit:8
>   ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/gerardpuig/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
>   Hit:9 ttp://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/unstable/ubuntu xenial InRelease
>   Get:10 ttp://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64
>   Packages [1,371 B] Fetched 110 kB in 0s (112 kB/s)
>   Reading package lists... Done E: The method driver
>   /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found. N: Is the package
>   apt-transport-https installed? E: Failed to fetch
>   ttps://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease   E:
>   Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
>   ones used instead.

(btw I remove the 'h' off 'http' since it said I can't post that many links)

I'm not sure what to do at this point. Am I installing the right version or should I be doing something different? I'm rather new to Ubuntu.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you installed apt-transport-https package?

Comment: Can you give me more info please? How do I do that?

Comment: k figured it out! That worked! If you want to post that as an answer I'll upvote ya! TYVM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wine repository uses `https`. You must install `apt-transport-https` package to access metadata and packages accessible over `https`